# Create partial of a string using pointers

Tags: c

Create partial of a given string using pointers in C.

Lets say I have the following string:

```
char string[] = "hellomynameisbob";
```

and I wanted hello out of it:

interface:

```
char * partial(int i, int j, char *string){
...
}
```

Where `j` is where I want my word to start at and `i` is where I want my word to end at.
Equivalent in Python would be:

```
string = "hellomynameisbob"
print string[0:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *partial(int a, int b, char *source) {
  char *buffer = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(source)+1); //Allocate new buffer
  strcpy(buffer, source+a); //Copy the string, starting at 'a'
  buffer[b-a] = 0; //Insert the terminating null character
  return buffer; //Don't forget to free it!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `partial` function is better written with an argument pointing to the buffer where you want the partial string to be copied. Otherwise it will have to dynamically allocate memory and the caller will have to free it, which is confusing.

```
// buf shall have size at least j - i + 2
char* partial(int i, int j, const char* string, char* buf) {
    return strncpy(buf, string + i, j - i + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
     char string[] = "hellomynameisbob";

     char buffer[7];

     snprintf(buffer,6,"%s", string );

     printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer );
```

Comment: I need to be able to save the variable and use it. Its not just for printing. I attempted playing with this and sprintf. But that turned out not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
char * partial(int i, int j, char *str)
{
    char * result = new char[j+1];
    snprintf  (result, j+1, str + i, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    char * result = partial(0, 5, "hellomynameisbob");
    std::cout << "Result=" << result << std::endl;
    delete result;
}
```

The output will be "hello"

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy(buf, string+i, j-i+1);
```

Do this inside partial function

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming j is starting point and i is end point 

char * partial(int i, int j, char *string){

      char *pstring;

      pstring = malloc((i-j)*sizeof(char)+1);

      memcpy(pstring,string+i,(i-j))

      pstring[i] = '\0';

      return pstring;
}
```